# Should I repeat the word "hand" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-usage, repetition

Should I repeat the word "hand" in this sentence?

> My right hand is holding my left **hand**.

Or, are there other ways to say that? For example:

> My right hand is holding **the other one**.

or simply:

> My right hand is holding my **left**.

I'd like to know what's more common to say.

Comment: In this context, _my left_ would be far more idiomatic than _my/the other one_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to omit the word "hand" and say "My right hand is holding my left".  We can understand that "left hand" is implied.

You can also use the pronoun "one": My right hand is holding my left one.